# Extra whitespace shows when using keyboard in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` that takes up all available space using the following method:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    //make sure web view takes up all space
    self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

This works fine, but when the keyboard is accessed, whitespace appears above the keyboard. This does not happen in Safari on the same web page.

Could you give me some ideas on how to fix this? I have no idea why this is happening.

[image: Whitespace]

Comment: Have you tested on actual device?

Comment: Please post a demo project.

Comment: try `bounds` instead of `frame`

Comment: can you Send html code of this page? B/C safari has status bar space on top but this page clear. also you can trick it by adding 30.0f to your webview hight. self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+30.0f);

Comment: @MiloGosnell the same thing happens on device

Comment: @BryanChen I tried bounds instead of frame, but now there is a whitespace without even opening up the keyboard.

Comment: @user1112691 the html is at http://demo.phppointofsalestaging.com/

Comment: you need to check the size of superview. try figure out which view the whitespace belong to by change background color or something

Comment: @BryanChen I will try that, that's a good idea

Comment: Will it work with autolayout (zero space to superview for each side)?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

i have just tested this page on iPad simulator i found no problem [image: also iPhone 3.5 is looking good]

i have uiwebview in nib file and attached to outlet

Comment: In 7.1 (just updated). It shows up fine on the simulator but incorrectly on the device.

Comment: It is working now on device. I thought I updated iPad to 7.1 but I didn't. It looks like 7.1 fixes this problem